# Excel VBA Print Just One Line

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using this code for add new items to next blank line.

```
    Private Sub Ekle_Butonu_Click()

    Dim LastRow As Long, ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Sayfa1

    LastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    ws.Range("A" & LastRow).Value = Tarih_B
    ws.Range("C" & LastRow).Value = Kaynak_B
    ws.Range("E" & LastRow).Value = Aciklama_B
    ws.Range("I" & LastRow).Value = Tutar_B

End Sub
```

And I want to print ***just*** this added line. Can you help me ?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look into the [`PageSetup.PrintArea`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pagesetup.printarea) property. For example:

```
Sub Test()

Dim lr As Long

With Sayfa1
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    .Cells(lr, 1).Value = Tarih_B
    .Cells(lr, 3).Value = Kaynak_B
    .Cells(lr, 5).Value = Aciklama_B
    .Cells(lr, 9).Value = Tutar_B
    .PageSetup.PrintArea = Replace("A?,C?,E?,I?", "?", lr)
    .PrintOut
End With

End Sub
```

---

As per your comment, If I understand you correctly, there are more cells in that same line you want to include:

```
.PageSetup.PrintArea = Replace("A?:J?", "?", lr)
```

Comment: Thanks this is good but it's just printing first coloumns. How can we modify it like ""Replace("A:B?,C:D?,E:H?,I:J?", "?", lr""

Comment: @Burak_4, I'm not sure what you mean. Your question is ***`And I want to print just this added line. Can you help me ?`***. Don't you just want these 4 values in your `PrintArea`? Please, check if the edited answer does the trick for you.

Comment: I mean, for example "aciklama" range is from E coloumn to H coloumn but it select just E coloumn in that line. And it's printing every piece of that area to per one page